# Does every UA Server come with discovery services?

Tags: opc-ua, opc

What's the difference between a regular OPC UA server and a Discovery Server such as LDS? I know that they are both UA Servers but what's the difference between them? What I could figure out from reading the specification is that all servers have a discovery URL where you discover the server with no security and a endpoint URL which is the "real" URL that you use to make a connection to the server. However, I have trouble understanding the registerServer() and findServers() for the UA server vs the discovery server. It seems like they both do the same thing?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with OPC UA, but are you asking about the concept of discovery-servers in-general? (Because it exists in pretty much every distributed services scheme like UDDI (service discovery) and OIDC/OAuth (IdP endpoint discovery), etc).

Comment: I am totally new to everything in the automation world and I was asking about OPC UA and I didn't even know it was standard thing. I would like to know the difference between server vs discovery servers. I'm not sure if other distributed services scheme also follow the server vs discovery servers

Answer (score 3):

Yes, every server supports part of the [Discovery Services](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/docs/Part4/5.4.1/), such as FindServers (locates server addresses) and GetEndpoints (lists available endpoints = security modes, in practice). But the normal server only provides information about itself.

The Local Discovery Server (LDS) supports also RegisterServer and can provide information of several servers (in the same computer or local network).

Comment: My understanding is that every server has 2 endpoints: the discoveryURL where clients can connect with no security and obtain the endpointURL from the discoveryURL. After that, the client connects to the endpointURL and can "officially" connect to the server. Is that right?

Also what's the process difference for connecting to just a UA Server vs a LDS?

Comment: You cannot really connect to an LDS, meaning you cannot make a session in it. So you can just call these services to register or find servers. OTOH, for the real server, you don't usually even need to call FindServers, since you already know the endpointUrl to connect to, so you just start by calling GetEnpoints and then follow with a new OpenSecureChannel on the selected endpoint and CreateSession. See the diagram in the spec that I linked above.

Comment: What about when a Server registers itself to the LDS? "Before a server registers with the LDS, it should call the GetEndpoints Service and choose the most secure endpoint supported by the LDS and then call RegisterServer2 or RegisterServer." Doesn't this mean the LDS Discovery URL need to be used by the server to connect? In addition doesn't a client have to connect to the discovery URL of the server to call GetEndpoints?

Comment: Yes, you need to open a socket connection to be able to call the necessary services. The servers need to know where to connect to, but they can assume it's at localhost:4840.

Comment: I am confused. You mentioned "You cannot really connect to an LDS, meaning you cannot make a session in it." What's the difference between that and the example I stated above about a server who wishes to register to the LDS needs to "choose the most secure endpoint supported by the LDS and then call RegisterServer2 or RegisterServer."

Comment: The OPC UA connection is established on several layers: socket, secure channel and session. The Discovery Services are used without a session, whereas all other OPC UA services are used with a session. I suggest you study the specification a bit more to get the details.